# Dijkstra's token termination algorithm in Promela

Tags: dijkstra, promela

My teacher has assigned us to program Dijkstra's token termination algorithm in Promela. Here is the algorithm:

"Every node maintains a counter c. Sending a message increases c by one; the receipt of a message decreases c by one. The sum of all counters thus equals the number of messages pending in the network.
When node 0 initiates a detection probe, it sends a token with a value 0 to node N-1. Every node i keeps the token until it becomes passive; it then forwards the token to node i-1 increasing the token value by c.
Every node and also the token has a color (initially all white). When a node receives a message, the node turns black. When a node forwards the token, the node turns white. If a black machine forwards the token, the token turns black; otherwise the token keeps its color.
When node 0 receives the token again, it can conclude termination, if
node 0 is passive and white,
the token is white, and
the sum of the token value and c is 0.
Otherwise, node 0 may start a new probe."

I somewhat get the idea, but I am having trouble really understanding what is going on. If someone could help explain exactly what the algorithm is doing step-by-step, that would be great. Also, while I don't want anyone writing the code for me, any tips on how to get started would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like half of the algorithm description is missing, was that explained in a different part of the lecture? Otherwise you may want to take a look at [this material](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/lehre/pda/ws0910/pda_ws0910_kapitel07.pdf)